# erro add chave ssh para conta no github

Tags: git, github

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]pessoal alguém estou tentando add minha chave ssh para conta no github so qe esta dando erro,
ele pede um titulo ai eu coloco "windows"
depois pede uma chave ai eu ponho "id_rsa.pub"
aparece esse erro: Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No título sugiro a você colocar algo que faça referência ao local que você está adicionando. Ex.: "Notebook Pessoal".

Supondo que você está utilizando um sistema Unix, na chave você deve colocar o conteúdo do arquivo `id_rsa.pub`, ele fica na pasta **$HOME/.ssh**, você pode verificar o contéudo do arquivo usando o comando `cat`: `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Explicação: O SSH usa criptografia assimétrica, que é baseada no uso de duas chaves: sendo uma (chave pública) usada pelo remetente para criptografar os dados antes de enviá-los, no seu caso o Github será o remetente, e a outra (chave privada) usada para recuperar a mensagem original, nesse caso a sua própria máquina.
Espero ter ajudado. =)

Comment: obrigado por responder, mais a solção era so ir na pasta que tinha sido gerada copiar o contedo dela e colar ali na chave